Unable to interact with Webview in react native android only
I am using a webview to show the cdc BMI calculator inside a view in react native. In iOS it loads and I am able to interact with the calculator, but on android while it will load, I cannot click and interact with the calc. It is being rendered from a flatlist if that makes any difference.
Here is the code for the webview
<Col style={{height:400,width:200,alignSelf:'center',display:item.TypicalAnswer=='Calculate using the CDC tool and enter the result in the "Answer" box below.'?'flex':'none',}}>
        <WebView
          style={{flex:1}}              
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          useWebKit={true}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          onMessage={(event) => console.log('webmsg', event)}
          onError={(error) => console.log('weberror', error.message)}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          mixedContentMode='never'
          source = {{uri:"https://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/adult-widget/iframe.html"}}
        />
    </Col>

Here is what the jsCode looks like
const jsCode = `document.querySelector('#show_embedcode').style.display = "none";
const meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum- 
scale=1.5, user-scalable=1');
meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
document.head.appendChild(meta);`;

I am using the latest version of react-native-webview@13.12.2

I found the issue. My flatlist was wrapped in a  After I remove that I am able to interact with the webview.
